# Column layout vertical align

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

I am hoping to achieve the following layout:

[image]

However, I cannot seem to get the text to align vertically properly.

I tried floating divs, but could not get it to work.

What is the simplest, most semantic way using the fewest elements of creating the above, not using tables?

Comment: Use table with `rowspan` and `colspan`

Comment: Hmm - I want to avoid that though. People tell me tables are evil for SEO, and should not be used for other markup

Comment: @T-ShirtDude +1 for suggesting my code

Comment: @jacktheripper tables are not evil for SEO. They're considered 'inelegant' if you're not using them for tabular data, but SEO has nothing to do there.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to use divs, do the following:

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <div style="float:left">left stuff</div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <div>right top stuff</div>
        <div>right bottom stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

give widths/heights as appropriate if needed

Comment: But the whole question is centred around vertical alignment, and so this answer is irrelevant

Comment: well, in that case you can add a 'display:table-cell' to the `<div>`s  though I think that's only compatible IE8 and above, or just use a table and be done with it :)

Comment: How? That should be your answer then!

Comment: @jacktheripper you can check here for other ways of vertically centering stuff http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `align="center"` on the element itself that you're looking for.

This works:

```html
<table border="1px" width="100px" height="100px">
   <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td align="center" width="50px" rowspan="2">HI</td>
             <td align="center" style="vertical-align:center;" width="100"> test </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td align="center" style="align:center;vertical-align:center;" width="100"> test2 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables are not a good options with the recent updates in html5

Answer (score 0):

> .wrapper {    border: 1px solid red;   overflow: hidden; width: 740px;  }
>
> .box {   height:300px;   width: 400px;   border: 1px solid blue; 
>         position: relative;
>       float: left; }
>
> .box2 {   width: 300px;   height: 200px;   position: relative;
>   border: 1px solid red;   overflow: hidden; }
>
> .inside {
>       position: absolute;
>       left: 93px;
>       top: 21px;
>       width: 135px;
>       height: 84px;
>       display: table;
>        }
>
> ```
> .inside p {
>   display: table-cell;
>   vertical-align: middle;
>   text-align: center;
> }
> ```

html

```
<div class="box">wererewrwe
</div>

 <div class="box2">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>inside</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works in all modern browsers and IE8+. If you need compatibility with IE6 and IE7 then I suggest using tables.

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right" style="background: red"><p>Text</p></div>
    <div class="right" style="background: blue"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>
```

and

```
div.block { width: 640px; height: 480px; border: solid 2px black; padding: 4px; }
div.left { float: left; width: 320px; height: 480px; background: green; }
div.right { float: right; width: 320px; height: 240px; display: table;}
div.right p { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }
```

You can see this example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XtXY9/1/).